# Why does nested query in SQLite return the wrong value?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm dealing with the yelp dataset on `sqlite3`, and I have a schema as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE businesses
     (business_id text primary key,
      name text,
      full_address text,
      city text,
      stars decimal(1,1),
      ratings integer);
```

I run the following query:

```
     select name, stars from businesses where ratings >= 400;
```

And I get the following:

```
    Pho Kim Long |3.5
    Pho So 1     |3.5
    Ichiza       |4
    ...
    Guy Fieri    |3.5
    Giada        |4
```

If I run:

```
    select name, min(stars) from businesses where ratings >= 400;
```

I get `The Quad Las Vegas Resort & Casino|2`

But if I run:

```
    select name 
    from (select name, min(stars) 
          from businesses 
          where ratings >= 400);
```

I get `Giada`.

I know that there's a way to do this with `LIMIT X`, but why does this occur in the first place? Is there something about the SQLite parser that I'm neglecting?

Comment: You should include rating and `The Quad Casino` on the sample data.

Comment: This query `select name, min(stars) from businesses where ratings >= 400` is technically incorrect as it does not have a `GROUP BY` clause. I think you need to use the query correctly defined by the standard in order to get the expected result

Comment: @cha you can use `min()` without `group by`

Comment: It would be better if tell us what you expect from your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), it says:

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY
>   clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated
>   once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the
>   result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the
>   dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each
>   non-aggregate expression.

In other words, the actual name you are getting is purely random in this case, it does not bear any relation to the row that actually has the minimum value of `stars`.

According to the SQL-92 standard, in a query containing aggregate expressions and non-aggregate expressions all of the non-aggregate expressions must appear in the GROUP BY clause. SQL-2003 has a similar but somewhat more complicated set of rules. This [blog article](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html) provides a summary.

Some databases allow making queries that include aggregate and non-aggregate expressions without any GROUP BY clause, or without all non-aggregates included in the GROUP BY clause, but as you have discovered the results may be indeterminate. Other databases will display an error and refuse to run the query.

It is hard to give specific advice on how to correct your query because you have not stated what output you are trying to get. If you are trying to find out which row has the minimum value of `stars` then one of the proposals in Juan's answer should work.

Comment: I understand what you say like `field, min(anotherfield)`. But just wonder, How I use `MIN()` in my sample is ok? Or also against SQL standars?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no your use of min() is ok: you do not include any non-aggregates in your subqueries so you don't need any grouping

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `MIN()` function bring the smallest value for `stars`, but not the name match for that row.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44391/2)

You can do a cross join

```
SELECT name
FROM businesses b,
     ( SELECT min(stars) as MinValue
       FROM businesses 
       WHERE ratings >= 400) as M
WHERE b.stars = M.MinValue;
```

OR Inner Select

```
SELECT name
FROM businesses b         
WHERE b.stars = ( SELECT min(stars) as MinValue
                  FROM businesses 
                  WHERE ratings >= 400);
```

Comment: I include a sql fiddle demo with both approach. I think first one is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite 3.7.11 or later guarantees that the values of unaggregated columns come from a row that matches the min() or max().

However, unless you are using one of the latest versions, the query planner will optimize away the min()/max() values if they are not returned from the query.
You *must* list the `min(stars)` in the outermost query.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct (and thus upvoted), but I'm not sure they quite get you from where you are to where you want to be.

### Why isn't the query's result predictable?

Typically, *aggregate functions* like MIN/MAX/COUNT are used with *GROUP BY* clauses.  For example:

```
-- Count the number of businesses per city
SELECT city, COUNT(1) FROM biz GROUP BY city;

-- Find the minimum rating of any business per city
SELECT city, MIN(stars) FROM biz GROUP BY city;
```

What happens when you omit the GROUP BY clause but keep the non-aggregated field ("city") in the query?  You're only going to get one MIN()imum, but which "city" will it be?  What if two or more cities are tied for lowest rated businesses?

```
-- Er, which city will it be?
SELECT city, MIN(stars) FROM biz;
```

Some RDBMS prohibit this construction entirely, and the SQL specs disallow it.* However, SQLite and some others will return a single row in this case, with the minimum rating across the entire table and an arbitrarily chosen "city".  You [**cannot rely on that row to represent all the aggregates**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset).  Indeed, depending on the RDBMS version it may not even represent *any* properly aggregated result.**  As you've seen, SQLite is free to pick one row sometimes, and another row other times.

### What should you be doing?

If I understand, you want to select the very worst rated restaurant(s) (lowest "stars"), but only of those restaurants with at least 400 reviews ("ratings").

Either of [@JuanCarlosOropeza's approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32430225/132382) work:  find `MIN(stars)` across all records `WHERE ratings >= 400` and then use that to select the `name` of each business whose `stars` equal that.  (SQL analytic function, [unsupported in SQLite](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions) at the time of this writing, offer more ways to compute the same.)

<sub>* As [@harmic notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32430226/132382), the situation is [a little more nuanced than that](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html).</sub>

<sub>** As [@CL. points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32433051/132382), later versions of SQLite do guarantee that the row selected does match the aggregate function.  That is, the `name` you get does actually have the `MIN(stars)` rating.</sub>